# Express routing post call unexpected token in json

Tags: json, express, post, routes

I need some help with my routing in Express and making a post call, and retrieving the data within the postrequest.

I've tried retrieving the data by loging req.body but that returns {}, I tried adding the bodyParser to my App.js which gets me the following error when I make a post call:

> POST http://localhost:3000/enquete/test/ 400 (Bad Request)

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0
```

This is my code:

**App.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , co = require('co')
  , assert = require('assert')
  , bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index.js');
var enqueteRouter = require('./routes/enquete.js');

// support parsing of application/json type post data
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//support parsing of application/x-www-form-urlencoded post data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/enquete', enqueteRouter);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/routes'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

**routes/enquete.js**

```
const express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

router.post('/test/', function(req,res,next){
  console.log('request:',req.body);
  res.send('hello');
})
module.exports = router;
```

**Ajax post call**

```
function save(array){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: { name: "Test", location: "TestUSA" },
        contentType: 'application/json',
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/enquete/test/',
                success: function(data) {
                        console.log('success');
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                },
                error: function(error) {
                        console.log('error:', error)
                 }
        });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/apps) to test the route? Make sure to select `x-www-form-urlencoded` as the body format since you're using `bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true })`

Comment: I've posted an img of postman. with body as you said, and key 'test', value 'test'

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/diorahman/1520485). Let us know if it helps.

Comment: Works, I'll change that code :) Thanks. I'm not sure what's wrong with mine though. Maybe the json.stringify was needed in the data post.